# CSS selectors stepper arrows

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, stepper

I have a stepper with an arrow pointing to the right from stage 1 to stage 5. 
I want to change the color of the previous and the next arrow for the current stage when I move my mouse over them.
The first problem is that I dont know how to get the arrows (pseudo elements) with css selectors and make them change color the same time with the span element.
The second problem it that the arrow of the current stage is red and the next arrow can not form a parallelogram.. It doesn't look nice

```css
.steps {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.steps strong {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.steps>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /* border: 1px solid #ddd; */
  padding: 12px 20px 8px 50px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 58px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .steps>li {
    float: left;
  }
  .steps .past {
    color: #777;
    background: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .steps .present {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c32611;
  }
  .steps .future {
    color: #777;
    background: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .steps strong {}
  .steps li>span:after,
  .steps li>span:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-width: 29px 30px;
  }
  .steps li>span:after {
    top: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-width: 34px;
  }
  .steps li>span:before {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .steps li.past+li>span:before {
    border-left-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .steps li.present+li>span:before {
    border-left-color: #c32611;
  }
  .steps li.future+li>span:before {
    border-left-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .steps li:first-child>span:after,
  .steps li:first-child>span:before {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Arrows at start and end */
  .steps li:first-child i,
  .steps li:last-child i {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-width: 30px;
  }
  .steps li:last-child i {
    left: auto;
    right: -30px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-bottom-color: white;
  }
```

```html
  <ul class="steps">
    <!--past present future-->
    <li class="past" onMouseOver="this.style.background='#e3e3e3'" onMouseOut="this.style.background='transparent'" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <span wicket:id="stage31"><strong>Stage 1</strong>Start</span><i></i></li>
    <li class="past" onMouseOver="this.style.background='#e3e3e3'" onMouseOut="this.style.background='transparent'" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <span wicket:id="stage32"><strong>Stage 2</strong>This is stage 2</span><i></i></li>
    <li class="present"><span><strong>Stage 3</strong>This is stage 3</span><i></i></li>
    <li class="future" onMouseOver="this.style.background='#e3e3e3'" onMouseOut="this.style.background='transparent'" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <span wicket:id="stage34"><strong>Stage 4</strong>This is stage 4</span><i></i></li>
    <li class="future"><span><strong>Stage 5</strong>Finish</span><i></i></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Note that you can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to add runnable code here on Stack Overflow, which will help answerers. First thing to try is the `:hover` pseudo-class, I expect.

Comment: Anyone running the code snippet - there's media queries making the result look different. You'll need to view it full-page to get the correct render.

Comment: When I implemented this kind of stepper, I always put the arrow in its own step, you have it in the next step which is targetable but not ideal in my opinion. Once you have the arrow in its own step, you just target it on hover. If you are looking to change visited steps, you will need js to add a class to the visited items and change the colours that way. Here is an example stepper https://www.lexus.ca/lexus/en/build-price/is

Comment: I have tried this rule

.steps li:hover + li > span:before { border-left-color:#e3e3e3; }

but the arrow of the current stage changes color from red to grey.

How can I select all the arrows expect for the current? or override the rule for the current arrow to stay red..